# asp.net MVC 4 with StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap, webactivator

I am converting an ASP.NET MVC3 project to MVC4.  I was trying to find the best approach to work with StructureMap and MVC4.  I've found a couple of solution which might work, but haven't tried them yet.

The first solution is very simple and [lightweight](http://biasecurities.com/2012/06/configuring-mvc-4-with-structuremap/).  The second one ([Structuremap.MVC4](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC4)) depends on WebActivator for the startup.

What is the better and simplest approach?  Do I still need to bootstrap everything and set the DependencyResolver with the WebActivator?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did the following and it works. hope it helps.

```
public class StructureMapDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IContainer _container;

        public StructureMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
            {

                return _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);

            }

            return _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances<object>().Where(s => s.GetType() == serviceType);
        }

    }
```

Global.asax:

```
     protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        var container = ConfigureDependencies();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    public static IContainer ConfigureDependencies()
    { 
        IContainer container = new Container();

        Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());
        var dataContext = new DataContext.DataContext();

        container.Configure(x => x.For<IRepository>().Use<Repository>().Ctor<DbContext>().Is(dataContext)); 
        container.Configure(x=>x.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>());

        return container;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I'll try your code and I'll get back to you with some feedback.

Comment: The section where you return a collection of services should be changed to  _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>()